# centos 7 systemd : Active: failed (Result: start-limit)

Tags: centos, systemd, services, uwsgi

I want to use uwsgi with my django project
I test `usgi --ini uwsgi.ini`  works well

And I want to write in `systemd` to control it
And face error

Here is my file

`/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for proj
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini  /usr/share/nginx/ENV/proj/proj/uwsgi.ini
StandardError=syslog
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=forking
NotifyAccess=main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

first time I use `systemctl restart  mysite.service`
it works well ,and then I use `systemctl stop mysite.service`
and then  restart again with `systemctl restart mysite.service`

But it can't restart after stop it
I got error :

```
proj.service - uWSGI for proj
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/proj.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2015-11-13 13:40:35 CST; 887ms ago
  Process: 4297 ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/nginx/ENV/proj/proj/uwsgi.ini (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4298 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 13 13:40:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: proj.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 13 13:40:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping uWSGI for proj...
Nov 13 13:40:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI for proj...
Nov 13 13:40:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: proj.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Nov 13 13:40:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI for proj.
Nov 13 13:40:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit proj.service entered failed state.
[root@localhost ~]# vim /lib/systemd/system/proj.service
```

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> proj.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.

This message is telling you, that you are restarting the service too frequently and `systemd` has integrated mechanism to detect it and block before the too many restarts will cause some trouble.

There are options `StartLimitInterval=` and `StartLimitBurst=` which modifies this behavior. You can read more in [manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

For this case, just add them in your `/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service` under the `[Unit]` section.

Comment: To improve on this answer, how doI set those options? (This could help others on the "TLDR;" manual page)

Answer (score 3):

```
Type=forking
NotifyAccess=main
```

This is another readiness protocol mismatch.  The doco tells you that the program speaks the systemd text-message readiness protocol.

```
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
```

## Further reading

- ["Systemd"](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Systemd.html). *uWSGI 2.0 Docs*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.